# How do I get taxi location data from api's like uber and ola cabs?

Tags: api, uber-api

I looked into it earlier and concluded the companies do not share this info, but recently I can across an app called "Scoot", which does the following:

"Using the app you can compare availability and real time ETA of cabs across different taxi services/aggregators like Ola Cabs, Uber, Taxiforsure"

How are they getting their info, anybody know?

Comment: Hi did you see Ryder app which is just like Scoot I dont understand how this guys are getting real time details from taxi companies?

Answer (score 2):

Uber's API has a public call to get time estimations for a given location, see here: [Uber API docs](https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/#time-estimates)

The rest of the services you mentioned doesn't seem to have a public API (or at least not one that I could access now). In such cases you might have to scrape their websites for the information you need, but keep in mind that the policy of the sites might prohibit such actions - I'd recommend contacting the companies behind those services and ask for permission.

Comment: Hi did you see Ryder app which is just like Scoot I dont understand how this guys are getting real time details from taxi companies?